# How to wait for a parallel command to finish before executing the next one ( Shell script)

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, wait

I have 3 python commands that are executed in parallel:

command_1A &
command_2A &
command_3A &

What I need is to wait for each one separately and when either of them finishes, a different command should be executed.
For example if command_1A finishes command_1B should be executed, if command_2A finishes command_2B should be executed and so on.

I found a solution to save the processes IDs and wait for all of them to finish, but that is not what I need. There might be an easy solution, but I am new to shell scripting and I could not find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Chains of jobs and running parallel jobs is pretty easy with `make`. Can you run `make -j3` instead of a shell? If yes, I can post an example.

Comment: Thank you @MarkSetchell. That was exactly what I needed. I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely this is all you need:

```
{ command1A; command1B; } &
{ command2A; command2B; } &
{ command3A; command3B; } &
```

That says to run:

- `command1A` followed by `command1B`, in parallel with,
- `command2A` followed by `command2B`, in parallel with,
- `command3A` followed by `command3B`

Don't try and omit any spaces or semi-colons to shorten the above.